# When creating a zip archive, what constitutes a duplicate entry

Tags: java, duplicates, zip

In a Java web application I am creating a zip file from various in-memory files (stored as byte[]).

Here's the key bit of code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    for (//each member of a collection of objects) {

        PDFDocument pdfDocument = //generate PDF for this member of the collection;
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(pdfDocument.getFileName());
        entry.setSize(pdfDocument.getBody().length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(pdfDocument.getBody());//pdfDocument.getBody() returns byte[]
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
    zos.close();
```

The problem: I'm sometimes getting a "ZipException: duplicate entry" when doing the "putNextEntry()" line.

The PDF files themselves will certainly be different, but they may have the same name ("PDF_File_for_John_Smith.pdf").  Is a name collision sufficient to cause this exception?

Comment: Thanks, all.  I added code to put the file names into a hash as they're generated and append a number if the name has already been used.

Comment: Thanks for the question; it's helped me figure out how I should avoid duplicates when writing zip files in java ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store 2 entries  with the same same name in a zip archive(in the same folder), much like you can't have 2 files with the same name in the same folder in a filesystem.

Edit; And while technically the zip file format allows this, the Java API for dealing with ZIP archives does not.

Comment: Note that this is actually a contradiction to ZIP file format's specification, however that specification is utterly dumb and shouldn't be followed :)

Comment: -1, you can store 2 entries with the same name in a ZIP archive in the same folder.

Comment: @dstibbe Not using the Java zip package.

Comment: You **can** store 2 entries with the same same name in a zip archive (in the same folder). But It is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- you can use a directory structure inside your ZIP file if you need to hold multiple files with the same file name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so.  Zip was originally intended to archive a directory structure, so it expects filenames to be unique.  You could add directories to keep your files separated (and provide extra information to differentiate them, if you want).